# Pluck only relevent keys from a map

Tags: java, hashmap, pattern-matching

I have an int arry input, for example : [1,3,4].

I also have a fixed/constant map of :

```
1 -> A
2 -> B
3 -> C
4 -> D
5 -> E
```

I want my output to be a corresponding string of all the relevant keys.

For our example of input [1,3,4], the output should be : "A,C,D".

What's the most efficient way of achieving that?

My idea was to iterate over the whole map, each time.
The problem with that, is that I have a remote call in android that fetches a long list of data items, and doing that for each item in the list seems a bit.. inefficient. Maybe there's something more efficient and/or more elegant. Perhaps using Patterns

Comment: my only idea was to iterate over the whole map, each time.  The problem with that, is that I have a remote call in android that fetches a long list of data items, and doing that for each item seems a bit.. inefficient.

Comment: you can cache that data, no need to perform http call again !

Comment: I am caching the fixed map. 
But on each server call the user performs, I have to output a string based on the input from server and the fixed map, just I like in the example above

Comment: It looks like your real problem is not iterating a map, which you can express in different ways (see answers below). My understanding is that you want to filter out values from your cached fixed map based on the input list, e.g. [1,3,4] above. That list, in turn, is fetched from server each time based on some user actions in the app. Correct?

Comment: user launches and refreshes something -> I call server, and get a list of ints , e.g [1,4,2]. 
But since 1,4,2 don't mean anything to the user, I need to convert that to their respective string value. These respective values are represented at the fixed mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array is defined as below along with the `HashMap`:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 3, 4 };
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();

// data in the map
hmap.put(1, "A"); hmap.put(2, "B"); hmap.put(3, "C"); hmap.put(4, "D"); hmap.put(5, "E");
```

Instead of iterating over the entire map, you can iterate over the array

```
String[] array = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(i -> hmap.get(i))
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .toArray(String[]::new);
```

This gives the output :

> A C D

---

As per your comment, to join it as one String you can use :

```
String str = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(i -> hmap.get(i))
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
```

Comment: could I make all the strings as one string in this format "str1/str2/str3" ?

Comment: Yes. `String array = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(i -> hmap.get(i)).filter(i -> i instanceof Object)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));`

Comment: it says it "requires api 24" .. my min api is 19. Are there any support libraries that can implement that for lower apis?

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Make sure you import this line `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: 1.8, and yes.. but the problem isn't with java it seems, but with android sdk api support.. I need my app to run on as low api as api 19, but this implementation requires 24 on all the methods of 'Arrays'

Comment: Maybe you can change the array(`arr`) to a list and try?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help :/

Comment: What is the issue with `list`?

Comment: the same thing with API requirement of `Arrays` method

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list of input instead of a map. That's the benefit of using a `Map` by the way, it has a lookup time of `O(1)` with proper hashing implemented. It would somewhat like :

```
Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> query = new ArrayList<>(); // your query such as "1,3,4"


List<String> information = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer integer : query) {
    String s = data.get(integer); // looking up here
    information.add(s);
}
```

which with the help of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) can be changed to

```
List<String> information = query.stream()
        .map(data::get) // looking up here
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // returns "A,C,D"
```

***Note***: I have used `String` and `Integer` for just a representation, you can use your actual data types there instead.